# Tor circuit for this site (-unknown-)

Tags: circuit

Whatever website I am on, it's never displayed in the "Tor circuit for this site" panel. It always says "(-unknown-)".

Is this a problem?

Comment: What operating system are you running this on?

Comment: I think it *could* be a problem, if only seeing the "unknown" address for all of them, this is where Tor pulls the hostname for circuit isolation from, so tabs would be using the same circuit. It'd be useful to try and find out where this is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you canonizing ironize for you response. Linux mint is the OS. I discovered that when I lowered the Tor Browser Security Settings to Low (default) and then loaded a webite the problem went away. Then I was able to raise the Security Settings back to my preferred setting of High and each subsequent website displayed correctly in the panel. Thanks again for taking the time to respond.